# Atlassian.SDK for visual studio

Tags: c#, jira

Подскажите пожалуйста. Package с нугета для вижуалки под названием Atlassian.sdk для работы с jira, является бесплатным или нет?

Comment: Если это не ясно из описания пакета, почему бы не спросить автора пакета?

Comment: [Тут](https://tproger.ru/articles/whats-difference-between-licenses/) есть краткое описание опенсурсных лицензий. Гляньте под какой распространяется `Atlassian.sdk`, а дальше думайте сами, каким образом будете использовать SDK и что позволяет лицензия.

Comment: @tym32167 я подумал, что возможно кто то пользовался уже этим софтом и хотел узнать у них.